# Mobile Website Overflow?

Tags: css, mobile, web, overflow

I started to create a mobile website and everything is fine and works, but one thing wont work. In any browser the overflow-x:hidden; work but when i check on my mobile I can scroll down up left right... I want to scroll only up and down. so i wanna disable the overflow X somehow... in my browser i have no problem but on my phone and other phones :/ same problem. I read an article that -webkit- and this should fix my problem in other android browsers but i cant find one website where is written how this works...

Comment: So your question is... You want an example of WebKit?

Answer (score 0):

The likely cause of this is that you've set a minimum width beyond the viewport. If you're definitely using;

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

There's no reason other than that the container is bigger than the viewport. Try setting a mobile media query that gives your container a max-width/width of 100%.

Webkit, or vendor prefixes very doubtfully have anything to do with this.

Comment: This code works only in Mobile Chrome but not in default android browsers : /